# How do I know which page I am on(react-native-swiper)?

Tags: react-native, react-native-swiper

I am developing a small app with React Native and I am using "react-native-swiper" in my app.
In this package "react-native-swiper", how do I know which page I am on now?
Can I get some value indicates which slide I am on such as slide index?
Now in the screen, there are 2 slides and every slides have same image which position is eccentric outside the slide. And I overlapped 2 images.

> The problem is that:

In android, while I push from slide 1 to slide 2, then pink image disappear, but not iOS.
So I want to control it's opacity according to the slide index.

How to get the slide index in "react-native-swiper"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `onIndexChanged` prop function `Called with the new index when the user swiped`
This will give you the index of the current slide.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working well perfectly.